# How to avoid the connection lines in geom_line or geom_path when there is no data?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm ploting a time series of mean values with geom_path and adding a ribbon with min max values with geom_ribbon. There are some gaps of data in the time series but the plot keep connecting the lines. In the attached plot the last panel show the gaps in the data. That data doesn't have x or y entries. Any way to control this?[image]

This is my plot code for the top panels:

```
ggplot(stat_total, aes(color=gas)) + 
  geom_path(aes(x=date_mean, y=conc_mean, color=gas), size=1.2, na.rm = T) +          
  geom_ribbon(aes(x=date_mean, ymin=conc_min, ymax=conc_max, fill=gas), color="grey70", alpha=0.4, na.rm = T)+
      scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "3 weeks" , date_labels = "%d-%b") + 
      xlab(NULL) +
      ylab('[ppb]') + 
      theme_bw() +
      facet_wrap(gas~.,scales = 'free_x',ncol = 1,nrow=2)
```

And a sample of the data:

```
structure(list(day = c(6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 
11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 
18L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 
14L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 
22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 
28L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 
13L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 
17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 
23L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 
30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 
18L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 
26L, 26L), month = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6), 
    gas = c("AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", 
    "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", 
    "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", 
    "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", 
    "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", 
    "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", 
    "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", 
    "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", 
    "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", 
    "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", 
    "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", 
    "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", 
    "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", 
    "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", 
    "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", 
    "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", 
    "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", 
    "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", 
    "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", 
    "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", 
    "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", 
    "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", 
    "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", 
    "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", 
    "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC", "AVOC", 
    "BVOC", "AVOC", "BVOC"), date_mean = structure(c(1549475100, 
    1549475100, 1549542360, 1549542360, 1549620787.5, 1549620787.5, 
    1549710663.15789, 1549710663.15789, 1549801042.10526, 1549801042.10526, 
    1549885680, 1549885680, 1549971100, 1549971100, 1550052300, 
    1550052300, 1550263680, 1550263680, 1550312871.42857, 1550312871.42857, 
    1550406436.36364, 1550406436.36364, 1550475600, 1550475600, 
    1550686320, 1550686320, 1550756700, 1550756700, 1551105981.81818, 
    1551105981.81818, 1551177428.57143, 1551177428.57143, 1551260700, 
    1551260700, 1551351176.47059, 1551351176.47059, 1551442263.15789, 
    1551442263.15789, 1551537771.42857, 1551537771.42857, 1551617052.63158, 
    1551617052.63158, 1551703500, 1551703500, 1551782925, 1551782925, 
    1552427550, 1552427550, 1552499742.85714, 1552499742.85714, 
    1552551075, 1552551075, 1552645800, 1552645800, 1552737120, 
    1552737120, 1552830942.85714, 1552830942.85714, 1552885875, 
    1552885875, 1553019075, 1553019075, 1553065457.14286, 1553065457.14286, 
    1553274000, 1553274000, 1553350725, 1553350725, 1553430857.14286, 
    1553430857.14286, 1553519076.92308, 1553519076.92308, 1553572800, 
    1553572800, 1553714100, 1553714100, 1553774717.64706, 1553774717.64706, 
    1553857842.85714, 1553857842.85714, 1553942057.14286, 1553942057.14286, 
    1553995800, 1553995800, 1554210800, 1554210800, 1554313000, 
    1554313000, 1554383442.85714, 1554383442.85714, 1554463080, 
    1554463080, 1554551672.72727, 1554551672.72727, 1554640740, 
    1554640740, 1554723600, 1554723600, 1554809760, 1554809760, 
    1555006320, 1555006320, 1555067250, 1555067250, 1555150950, 
    1555150950, 1556319600, 1556319600, 1556373600, 1556373600, 
    1556453400, 1556453400, 1556533800, 1556533800, 1556646300, 
    1556646300, 1556707628.57143, 1556707628.57143, 1556797800, 
    1556797800, 1556888123.07692, 1556888123.07692, 1556974800, 
    1556974800, 1557050072.72727, 1557050072.72727, 1557869400, 
    1557869400, 1557914563.63636, 1557914563.63636, 1558005726.31579, 
    1558005726.31579, 1558092937.5, 1558092937.5, 1558178600, 
    1558178600, 1558265611.76471, 1558265611.76471, 1558351376.47059, 
    1558351376.47059, 1558436400, 1558436400, 1558525050, 1558525050, 
    1558612164.70588, 1558612164.70588, 1558699300, 1558699300, 
    1558783320, 1558783320, 1558874400, 1558874400, 1558935600, 
    1558935600, 1559079900, 1559079900, 1559128950, 1559128950, 
    1559216747.36842, 1559216747.36842, 1559301900, 1559301900, 
    1559387300, 1559387300, 1559474258.82353, 1559474258.82353, 
    1559561717.64706, 1559561717.64706, 1559649494.11765, 1559649494.11765, 
    1559733300, 1559733300, 1559816485.71429, 1559816485.71429, 
    1559908270.58824, 1559908270.58824, 1559994750, 1559994750, 
    1560075187.5, 1560075187.5, 1560612150, 1560612150, 1560686600, 
    1560686600, 1560744720, 1560744720, 1560897000, 1560897000, 
    1560945494.11765, 1560945494.11765, 1561031258.82353, 1561031258.82353, 
    1561124353.84615, 1561124353.84615, 1561174650, 1561174650, 
    1561397760, 1561397760, 1561469250, 1561469250, 1561509600, 
    1561509600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    conc_mean = c(2.21485, 4.51665, 1.07492666666667, 3.61554666666667, 
    1.2719875, 3.3012125, 0.765063157894737, 3.71997368421053, 
    0.375805263157895, 1.10004210526316, 0.675033333333333, 1.17912, 
    1.23057222222222, 3.79774444444444, 0.204633333333333, 0.578241666666667, 
    0.54028, 0.23396, 0.702907142857143, 0.971378571428571, 0.813372727272727, 
    1.31120909090909, 0.87175, 1.3416, 1.15376, 3.93216, 0.3061, 
    1.58768333333333, 0.325572727272727, 0.530245454545455, 0.735842857142857, 
    1.18681428571429, 0.489575, 0.8701375, 0.431847058823529, 
    0.618288235294118, 0.572268421052632, 1.00910526315789, 0.475021428571429, 
    1.11840714285714, 0.437810526315789, 0.73228947368421, 0.677941666666667, 
    1.26760833333333, 0.4298875, 0.667275, 0, 0.141375, 0.396471428571429, 
    0.566985714285714, 0.562175, 0.5603625, 0.415214285714286, 
    1.04814285714286, 0.139766666666667, 0.1184, 0.158435714285714, 
    0.493435714285714, 0.738375, 2.1870375, 0.5032125, 1.860325, 
    0, 0, 0.80184, 1.6749, 0.629425, 1.32535, 0.621492857142857, 
    2.09426428571429, 0.521784615384615, 0.8041, 0.0966, 0.02106, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.11013, 
    0.45911, 0.945981818181818, 2.15627272727273, 0.44487, 0.68837, 
    0.8569, 1.47154444444444, 0.40066, 0.88519, 0, 0, 0.278175, 
    0.1233125, 0.199175, 0.108025, 0.1002, 0.1679, 0.157933333333333, 
    0.303033333333333, 0.231433333333333, 0.330433333333333, 
    0.5878, 0.694266666666667, 1.13938333333333, 0.78425, 3.01142142857143, 
    0.8532, 2.96855333333333, 0.905413333333333, 2.63885384615385, 
    0.831161538461539, 0.0564933333333333, 0.110113333333333, 
    0.0251636363636364, 0.0381454545454545, 0.032775, 0.070375, 
    0.171754545454545, 0.179809090909091, 0.868431578947368, 
    0.290926315789474, 1.460875, 0.3505375, 0.515116666666667, 
    0.2017, 0.170970588235294, 0.0566647058823529, 2.00161764705882, 
    0.891194117647059, 2.27995882352941, 1.07888823529412, 0.4599, 
    0.172966666666667, 0.292129411764706, 0.3191, 1.30511111111111, 
    0.858427777777778, 0.90774, 0.82456, 0.538777777777778, 0.221883333333333, 
    0.509583333333333, 0.280516666666667, 0.24795, 0.14805, 0.08165, 
    0.09388125, 0.0355947368421053, 0.0266210526315789, 0.0540666666666667, 
    0.0445833333333333, 0.0329111111111111, 0.0137111111111111, 
    0.431323529411765, 0.138288235294118, 0.946082352941176, 
    0.597052941176471, 0.0175, 0.00785294117647059, 0.03314375, 
    0.019, 0.04485, 0.0101714285714286, 1.12921176470588, 0.166876470588235, 
    2.01030625, 1.2114875, 1.25706875, 0.54935, 0.0532833333333333, 
    0.05245, 0.0311222222222222, 0.00601666666666667, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.168461538461538, 0.0720230769230769, 0, 
    0, 0.46362, 0.17162, 0.347108333333333, 0.1352, 0.255366666666667, 
    0.0637), conc_min = c(0.9481, 1.016, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1382, 
    0.4736, 0.1568, 0.2592, 0.1855, 0.1443, 0.3351, 0.4526, 0.0364, 
    0.0148, 0.3338, 0.0614, 0.1845, 0.193, 0.298, 0.2129, 0, 
    0, 0.182, 0.3781, 0.1973, 0.5151, 0, 0, 0.289, 0.0466, 0.076, 
    0.0312, 0.1458, 0.0806, 0.1124, 0.0219, 0.1038, 0.0628, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0911, 0, 0, 0.3236, 0.0391, 0.0757, 0.0159, 
    0.0289, 0, 0.0117, 0.0052, 0.1448, 0.1749, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0.2611, 0.1329, 0.1001, 0.6807, 0.0311, 0.0042, 0.0149, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0.2353, 0.5611, 0.0524, 0.0392, 0.2764, 0.3357, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1002, 0.1679, 0.0878, 0.2908, 0, 0, 0.4953, 
    0.4679, 0.7842, 0.2518, 1.1497, 0.4129, 1.4005, 0.3776, 1.0426, 
    0.3828, 0.0077, 0.0047, 0, 0, 0.026, 0.0039, 0.0241, 0.0029, 
    0.0522, 0.0555, 0.1238, 0.0305, 0.025, 0.0009, 0.0211, 0.0007, 
    0.035, 0.0093, 0.2304, 0.1012, 0.0358, 0.0139, 0.0711, 0.0259, 
    0.2234, 0.1971, 0.012, 0, 0.0079, 0, 0, 0, 0.0348, 0.0258, 
    0.006, 0, 0.0055, 0, 0.0081, 0, 0.0109, 0, 0.0144, 0, 0.0276, 
    0.0015, 0.0047, 0, 0.007, 0, 0.0114, 0, 0.0062, 0, 0.2045, 
    0.3129, 0, 0, 0.0173, 0.0009, 0.0123, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1093, 0.0679, 0.0855, 0.0256, 0.0927, 
    0.0266), conc_max = c(5.2082, 9.4515, 2.6412, 9.5067, 3.374, 
    10.2935, 1.9887, 7.3334, 1.1261, 2.2172, 2.521, 2.9801, 3.3107, 
    7.9089, 0.701, 1.181, 0.9013, 0.7176, 1.3709, 2.6799, 2.4004, 
    2.6443, 1.7978, 3.5656, 2.2826, 9.0001, 0.4704, 3.1122, 1.1959, 
    1.0669, 1.8055, 2.8748, 1.4114, 2.7354, 0.9683, 1.6872, 1.7906, 
    3.068, 1.1533, 3.1572, 1.61, 1.8917, 3.1135, 3.3496, 0.8959, 
    1.6323, 0, 0.1973, 1.1029, 1.7997, 1.0299, 1.3705, 1.7949, 
    5.4322, 0.4341, 0.3075, 0.6009, 1.5614, 1.6237, 6.4092, 1.6444, 
    4.1521, 0, 0, 1.6438, 4.4297, 1.512, 2.4371, 2.0231, 6.2908, 
    1.5731, 2.59, 0.3182, 0.0694, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5511, 2.499, 1.596, 3.4777, 1.018, 
    1.5773, 1.8561, 2.5637, 1.0436, 3.3362, 0, 0, 1.3413, 0.3713, 
    0.6086, 0.4185, 0.1002, 0.1679, 0.2585, 0.3129, 0.6006, 0.7198, 
    0.668, 1.1023, 1.8961, 1.2774, 6.3908, 1.2608, 5.7836, 1.9329, 
    4.8889, 2.1084, 0.4252, 0.5633, 0.0532, 0.1212, 0.0488, 0.262, 
    0.3876, 1.006, 3.4004, 1.1248, 4.1029, 1.2065, 2.13, 0.6134, 
    0.7077, 0.2737, 6.3182, 2.0403, 6.3883, 2.3115, 1.4964, 0.5299, 
    1.2378, 0.9909, 4.1648, 2.5412, 4.6703, 2.0224, 2.8942, 0.9106, 
    1.1358, 0.7632, 0.4456, 0.2783, 0.4417, 0.5307, 0.0934, 0.1239, 
    0.2766, 0.2853, 0.1005, 0.1172, 4.3601, 1.3379, 4.5632, 2.9013, 
    0.0615, 0.0915, 0.0648, 0.1201, 0.1214, 0.0886, 7.008, 1.001, 
    4.6935, 5.0903, 7.8913, 1.6407, 0.1217, 0.2257, 0.1106, 0.0603, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.0643, 0.5233, 0, 0, 0.6608, 0.2956, 
    0.8226, 0.3397, 0.3421, 0.1225)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -202L))
```

Comment: I don't think there's a clear way for `ggplot2` to *know* that there should be a gap is if there is an `NA`. If there are gaps, then that row must be *present*, with a valid `date_mean` and a value of `NA`.

Comment: Try `ggplot(data.frame(x=c(1:5,1:5,1:5), y=c(rep(0,5), c(1,1,NA,1,1), rep(2,5)), g=rep(1:3, each=5)), aes(x,y,group=g)) + geom_line()` to see what I mean.

Comment: (The first comment should have read *"I think the only clear way for `ggplot2` to know ..."*.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is another one that was slightly more complicated than I originally thought, but I think I have a solution that seems to work.  At first glance, it seems you could just set `data=stat_total[which(stat_total$conc_mean!=0),]`, which would mean only those values greater than 0 would be plotted... but that doesn't work.  The reason is simply that `ggplot` will still connect the line all the way through via `geom_path` and draw the ribbon via `geom_ribbon`, since data exists to the right and left of those 0 values.

The key here is to understand that we want to change and assign the `group=` aesthetic.  This controls connectivity of geoms like lines.  It's easily demonstrated via the following:

```
d <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10, grp=c(rep(1,4),2,rep(3,5)))
ggplot(d, aes(x,y)) + theme_bw() + 
    geom_line(aes(group=grp)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

So the theoretical solution to your example will involve getting a `group=` aesthetic to apply to "sections" of `stat_total$conc_mean` that don't equal zero, while also just not plotting when `stat_total$conc_mean` equals zero.  Critically, the "sections" need to have different `group=` aesthetic values.  If they don't, then we'll just get the whole thing connected like you have now, since again--there still exists data to the right and left of those zeros, so `ggplot` will just draw a line through them.

#### Solution

First, I arranged your data frame by `stat_total$gas` and then `stat_total$date_mean`.

```
df <- arrange(stat_total, gas, date_mean)
```

Then, I wanted to

(1) **create a column that basically indicated when `stat_total$conc_mean` was 0 or contained a value > 0.**  I concede there is probably a more elegant to accomplish the goal here without this step, but this part also makes it easier to follow the solution.

```
df$a <- ifelse(df$conc_mean==0, NA, 1)
```

(2) **Use a function to create a new grouping column.**  The function steps through a vector and stores a count number (`g_num`) into a return vector in that position when there is a number, but stores `NA` and increments `g_num` when it finds an `NA`.  The result is a return vector that has the sequence of numbers we want here.

```
my_func <- function(x) {
  g_num <- 1
  return_vect <- vector(mode='double',length=length(x))
  for(i in 1:length(x)) {
    if (is.na(x[i])){
      return_vect[i] <- NA
      g_num <- g_num+1
    }
    else {
      return_vect[i] <- g_num
    }
  }
  return(return_vect)
}

# create the new column
df$g <- my_func(df$a)
```

An example of how it works is shown below:

```
> test <- c(1,1,1,NA,NA,1,1,NA,1,1)
> test
 [1]  1  1  1 NA NA  1  1 NA  1  1
> my_func(test)
 [1]  1  1  1 NA NA  3  3 NA  4  4
```

(3) **Plot it.** It's the same as your original code, but we use the new column as the `group=` aesthetic, and also only plot values > 0 for `stat_total$conc_mean` (so you avoid getting a line at the bottom of the graph for certain sections.

```
ggplot(df[which(df$conc_mean!=0),], aes(color=gas, group=g)) + 
  geom_path(aes(x=date_mean, y=conc_mean, color=gas), size=1.2, na.rm = T) +          
  geom_ribbon(aes(x=date_mean, ymin=conc_min, ymax=conc_max, fill=gas), color="grey70", alpha=0.4, na.rm = T)+
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "3 weeks" , date_labels = "%d-%b") + 
  xlab(NULL) +
  ylab('[ppb]') + 
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(gas~.,scales = 'free_x',ncol = 1,nrow=2)
```

[image]